# ValueError: save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'sender'

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to create Message obj while creating an object for Quotation. i've tried looking at the official Django docs, but it doesn't seem to apply. I don't know where is the error.

```
class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="sender_user")
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="recipient_user")
    sender_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    recipient_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    parent_msg = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, blank=True, related_name="parent")
    subject  = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    message = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

and here is my Quotation Table

```
class Quotation(models.Model):
    editor = models.ForeignKey(Editors)
    discipline = models.ForeignKey(Discipline, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    words_count = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Students, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True,   blank=True)
modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

and here is my view function:

```
quotation = Quotation.objects.create(
    editor=editor,
    student=student,
    title=form.cleaned_data['title'],
    discipline = discipline,
    description = form.cleaned_data['description'],
    words_count=form.cleaned_data['words_count']
)
quotation.save()

create_message = Message.objects.create(
    sender= User(username=quotation.student.user.username),
    recipient=User(username=quotation.editor.user.username),
    subject=quotation.title,
    messages=quotation.description
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use, `Quotation.objects.create`, Django will automatically create AND save the object to the database. Hence, `quotation.save()` should be removed as it's unnecessary.

On top of this, using `User(...)` will NOT save the object into the database. You still need to call `save` OR use the above mentioned solution (`create`) before inserting the users for `sender` and `receiver` foreign keys.

`views.py`:

```
quotation = Quotation.objects.create(
    editor=editor,
    student=student,
    title=form.cleaned_data['title'],
    discipline = discipline,
    description = form.cleaned_data['description'],
    words_count=form.cleaned_data['words_count']
)

sender = User.objects.create(username=quotation.student.user.username)
receiver = User.objects.create(username=quotation.editor.user.username)
create_message = Message.objects.create(
    sender= sender,
    recipient=receiver,
    subject=quotation.title,
    messages=quotation.description
)
```

Comment: yeah i have removed that but still getting the same error

Comment: No you haven't seen my edit. I have changed the way you create your `Message` object.

Comment: quotation = Quotation.objects.create(
    editor=editor,
    student=student,
    title=form.cleaned_data['title'],
    discipline = discipline,
    description = form.cleaned_data['description'],
    words_count=form.cleaned_data['words_count']
 )

create_message = Message.objects.create(
    sender= User(username=quotation.student.user.username),
    recipient=User(username=quotation.editor.user.username),
    subject=quotation.title,
    message=quotation.description
)

Comment: yeah thanks, that error got removed but getting new error.

Comment: UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username

Comment: Please provide the full stacktrace

Comment: Wait are `student.user` and `editor.user` from django's `User` model??

Comment: i have corrected that by replacing create by get. thank you somuch